# Calling Methods from classes in Sprite kit?

Tags: xcode, audio, methods, sprite-kit

Ok, time to ask. I have a method in my `player.m` file called `musicOn`. Here is my classes. On startup it plays the music, and across all scenes, but my buttons in my `MainMenu` to turn off and on music are not working. What am I doing wrong?

**Player.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Player : NSObject{


}

+ (Player *) musicOn;
+ (Player *) musicOff;

@end
```

**Player.m**

```
#import "Player.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@import AVFoundation;

@interface Player()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer * backgroundMusicPlayer;

@end

static Player *musicOff = nil;
static Player *musicOn = nil;

@implementation Player

//Music on Method.
+ (Player *) musicOn {

NSLog(@"Music on method called");

if (!musicOn) {

    musicOn = [[super allocWithZone:nil]init];

    //Play Music.
    NSError *error;
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"music" withExtension:@"wav"];
    musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"Music on");

}
    return musicOn;

}

//Music off Method.
+ (Player *) musicOff {

NSLog(@"Music off method called");

if (!musicOff) {

    musicOff = [[super allocWithZone:nil]init];

    [musicOff.backgroundMusicPlayer stop];

    NSLog(@"Music off");
}

return musicOff;

}

//Overwriting allocWithZone.
+(id) allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

return [self musicOn];
return [self musicOff];
}

//Overwriting init.
- (id) init {

self = [super init];

if (self) {

    _backgroundMusicPlayer = self.backgroundMusicPlayer;

}
return self;
}


@end
```

**MainMenu.m**

```
//Calling the method from Player class.
[Player musicOn];
```

**The log is showing this**

```
2014-01-16 21:23:04.010 Sprite Test[12582:60b] Music on method called
2014-01-16 21:23:04.035 Sprite Test[12582:60b] Music on
2014-01-16 21:23:04.065 Sprite Test[12582:60b] Music on
2014-01-16 21:23:04.068 Sprite Test[12582:60b] soundOn Called

2014-01-16 21:23:08.641 Sprite Test[12582:60b] Music off method called
2014-01-16 21:23:08.643 Sprite Test[12582:60b] Music off
2014-01-16 21:23:08.646 Sprite Test[12582:60b] Music off
2014-01-16 21:23:08.649 Sprite Test[12582:60b] soundOff Called

2014-01-16 21:23:09.304 Sprite Test[12582:60b] Music on method called
2014-01-16 21:23:09.306 Sprite Test[12582:60b] Music on
2014-01-16 21:23:09.307 Sprite Test[12582:60b] soundOn Called
```

Comment: you're creating new view controller instances, you need to use a reference to the existing one.

Comment: The soundOn and soundOff nodes are not being removed... You will find they are being added on top of each other.

Comment: @akashg Thank you, I forgot to remove the node when the other is displayed, I have fixed this now. Thanks. Are you able to help with the singleton?

Comment: I edited my post, it could help you solve your problem.

Comment: @Remyoman I edited my code above since I made a singleton class, it changes everything. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewController.m`, edit the method `-musicOn` as follows:

```
if (self.backgroundMusicPlayer == nil)
{
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
}
```

Also, you need to create a singleton of the viewController class. Only then will you be able to access the specific AVAudioPlayer instance that is playing the music.

Please change the class method for singleton as follows:

```
+ (Player *) musicOn {

NSLog(@"Music on method called");

    @synchronized (self)
    {
        if (!musicOn) {

            musicOn = [[super allocWithZone:nil]init];
        }

    }
    //Play Music.
    NSError *error;
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"music" withExtension:@"wav"];
    musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"Music on");

}
    return musicOn;

}
```

Comment: I'm creating a singleton class called `Player`, Should I move my methods out of the viewController and into the `Player`?

Comment: I added my method after creating a singleton class, the sound turns on when the app opens, turns off when hitting off, but when hitting on, the method gets called but not the Music on in the IF statement. Do you know why?

Comment: Yeah you should move the methods yo the singleton class.

Answer (score 3):

In your MainMenu.m you are creating a new instance each time the button is pressed with the code: `ViewController *musicInstance = [[ViewController alloc] init];` followed by
`[musicInstance musicOn];` You are also doing this when you are turning the music off again.

Make sure you static Player variable isn't inside the method or you will be creating new `AVAuidioPlayer` instances instead of keeping one.
Does below code help you Player class?

```
static Player *musicOn = nil; // <-- Shouldn't be in the method.

+ (Player *)musicOn 
{
    NSLog(@"Music on method called");
    if (!musicOn) 
    {
        musicOn = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
        NSError *error;
        NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"music" withExtension:@"wav"];
        musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
        musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
    [musicOn.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
    NSLog(@"Music on");
    return musicOn;
}
```

Comment: I made a singleton class called Player, so this is how I am calling it now. [Player musicOn];

Comment: I moved the static variable outside the method, same issue. After each method is called once, it will call the method, but its not calling inside the IF statement. I assume thats because its not nil, I've put a log to see if it is nil, and its not, but it's not returning or something.